# Pre calc inequalities with equal sign

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

When solving inequities with an equal sign like

$$|4x+4|=4$$

This is just a random equation but say you get the solutions $x=a,b$ is this wrote as $x=a$ or $x=b$ or is it wrote as $x=a$ and $x=b$ I know you have to check to see if they satisfy the inequality but I just am looking to this the proper saying, thanks!

Comment: "$x=a$ is a solution and $x=b$ is another solution" is one way to write it.  "The solutions are $x=a$ and $x=b$" another way.  "If $|4x+4|=4$ then $x=a$ or $x=b$" is another way of writing it.  Note that we want to avoid accidentally implying that $x$ is simultaneously equal to $a$ and $b$ since that is impossible in the case that $a$ is different than $b$.

Comment: &JMoravitz so both are correct??

Comment: No, only or is correct. Using and implies that x is both a and b at the same time

Comment: Depending on context and surrounding words, yes potentially you *could* use "and."  But again, depending on the surrounding words the "and" might be interpreted as both conditions occur simultaneously which we want to avoid.  An example of an obviously incorrect way to write this would be "The one solution is for $x=a$ and $x=b$ to simultaneously be true"  There is a lot of grey in between obviously good and obviously wrong ways to write this.  A part of learning to write mathematics is to pick phrasings which can't be misinterpreted.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$x\in\{a,b\} \iff x\in\{a\}\cup\{b\} \iff x=a \,\lor\, x=b$$

but

$$x=a \,\land\, x=b \iff x=a=b$$

therefore in general we say preferably that the solution is $x=a$ or $x=b$ but we can also say, more informally, that the solutions are $a$ and $b$.